# How to set headers with axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

im trying to get information from an api football that I found.
On postman it works well but i cannot set the headers properly with axios.

here is my code :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  getTest = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'X-Auth-Token': '97e0d315477f435489cf04904c9d0e6co',
    };

    axios.get("https://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/90/matches?status=SCHEDULED", {headers})
      .then(res => {
        console.log("DATA")
      })
      .catch(res => {
        console.log("ERR", res);
      });
  }

    render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getTest}>info</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What is the problem ?
Thx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set headers in axios as follows:

```
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-Auth-Token': '97e0d315477f435489cf04904c9d0e6co',
};
axios.get(url, {headers})
```

Comment: Hello, I did and it doesnt work.
I got this "from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response." It seems that it worked but what am I supposed to do with this ?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config. Also confirm server is receiving token by 'X-Auth-Token' or 'authorization'

Comment: No it works its ok its just I got an error about Access Control when i set it to '*' in my headers